# Bootstrap 4 creating non modal dialog box

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm want to create a non modal dialog box using bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried by overriding **model**  class as below

```
.modal{
  top:10%;
  left:50%;
  bottom:auto;
  right:auto;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
```

Can someone please help me out

Comment: Can you share more detail about that what do you want?

Comment: After opening modal dialog, I should able to perform actions on other parts of page.

Comment: Is it really 'model' or 'modal'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to your modal, named modalless. Like this -

```
<div class="modal fade modalless" id="myModal">
```

Then in CSS, do the following. Now it should work.

```
.modalless{
    top:10%;
    left:50%;
    bottom:auto;
    right:auto;
    margin-left:-300px;
}
```

Check this [link](https://codepen.io/DrDoZeR/pen/ZWBZvz) for an example.

Comment: It is not working for me @Sujit Agarwal. 
Below is the link.
https://jsfiddle.net/Thirdparty987/g1r0p9zs/2/

Comment: Check my edited fiddle. I've added  `data-backdrop="false"` and it works. 
            https://jsfiddle.net/g1r0p9zs/3/

Comment: Great @Sujit Agarwal. Thanks